# How can I display the output of the parameters I have set from a child class?

Tags: java, inheritance, abstract-class, display

*I need help accessing the variables I have inputted using the child class. I made an object for the child class in my main class, however, I do not know how will I have access to the inputs I have entered and display them at the end of the code.*

```
public abstract class player {
    public abstract String name(String name);
    public abstract void race(int race);
    public abstract int[] getStatArray();
}

import java.util.Scanner;
public class childplayer extends player {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    public String name(String name) {
        System.out.print("Enter your name: ");
        name = sc.nextLine();
        return name;
    }
    
    public void race(int race) {
        System.out.println("Race options: ");
        System.out.println("\t 1 - Human \n\t 2 - Elf \n\t 3 - Orc \n\t 4 - Angel \n\t 5 - Demon");
        System.out.print("Enter character's race: ");
        race = sc.nextInt();
        if((race>5)||(race<1)) {
            while ((race>5)||(race<1)) {
                System.out.print("Enter character's race: ");
                race = sc.nextInt();
            }
        }System.out.println(" ");
    }
    
    public int[] getStatArray(){
        int [] stat = new int [3];
        int x = 0, y = 0, pts = 0;
        System.out.println("Enter character's stats.");
        while(y<3) {
            System.out.print("Enter value: ");
            x = sc.nextInt();
            y++;
            pts = pts + x;
        }
        int i = 0;
        if(pts>10) {
            System.out.println("Invalid input. Try again.");
            while(i<3) {
                System.out.print("Enter value: ");
                x = sc.nextInt();
                i++;
                pts = pts + x;
            }
        }else {
            stat[i] = x;
            i++;
        }
        
        return stat;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep the values to use later then you need to store them. The best way to do this is simply with a class variable like so:

```
public class Childplayer extends Player {

    //Create class variables that store the values
    String name = "";
    int race = -1;
    int[] stat = new int [3];
```

Then we just modify your methods to use these variables, for example:

```
public String name(String name) {

    //Process the name
    if (someCondition) {
        name = name +" Smith"
    }

    //Saved the passed in variable to the class variable `this.name`
    this.name = name;

    return this.name;
}
```

And another example:

```
public void race(int race) {
    //Saved the passed in variable to the class variable `this.race`
    this.race = race:
}
```

Then to get the information later we simply use:

```
// Earlier in the code
Childplayer playerA = new Childplayer();

// Some code here
//...

// Later in the code we can get the values
String name = playerA.name;
int storedRaceFromEarlier = playerA.race;
```

---

I strongly recommend making use of a constructor method to populate the class data. I have simplified the code and value checking for the sake of this example:

```
//Note that Java naming conventions require that classes should always have a capital letter at the start, I have fixed this in my example
public abstract class Player {
    //Example getter abstract methods that must be implemented
    public abstract String getName();
    public abstract int getRace();
    public abstract int[] getStatArray();
}

// Note that Java naming conventions require that classes should always have a capital letter at the start, I have fixed this in my example
public class Childplayer extends Player {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    //Create class variables that store the values
    String name = "";
    int race = -1;
    int[] stat = new int [3];

    // Constructor method with exactly the same name as the class "Childplayer"
    // This method should be responsible for creating the object and populating data
    Childplayer() {
        //Set name
        System.out.print("Enter your name: ");
        name(sc.nextLine());
        System.out.print("Name set as " + name + "\r\n");
        
        // Set race
        System.out.println("Race options: ");
        System.out.println("\t 1 - Human \n\t 2 - Elf \n\t 3 - Orc \n\t 4 - Angel \n\t 5 - Demon");
        int result = -1;

        while ((result > 5) || (result < 1)) {
            System.out.print("Enter character's race: ");
            result = sc.nextInt();
        }

        // Set the race with the abstract method
        race(result);
        System.out.print("Race set as " + race + "\r\n");
        
        System.out.println("Enter character's stats.");
        int i = 0;

        while (i < 3) {
            System.out.print("Enter stat value: ");
            //Save the stat to the class variable
            stat[i] = sc.nextInt();
            i++;
        }
    }

    // Abstract methods implemented to return the correct values
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getRace() {
        return race;
    }

    public int[] getStatArray() {
        return stat;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks! but we are required to use abstract class

Comment: You asked how to store inputs and access them later, and the solution as shown at the start of my answer is to use class variables. The part about using a constructor is just good practice, however, the example does make use of the abstract methods to get the data later.

Comment: @trese I have updated my answer to highlight the use of the class variables. Use them as you will. Note that the abstract methods shown in your question make no sense. The abstract methods should all be getter methods `getName()`, `getRace`, and `getStarts()` with a single constructor method to populate them.